# Why cant I run my python Binary Search| ans = BinarySearch(x,14) as Error

Tags: python, binary-search

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,5,14,24,31,53])

def BinarySearch(Arr,search_value):
    lower_bound = 0
    upper_bound = len(Arr) - 1

    while lower_bound <= upper_bound:

        midpoint = (lower_bound + upper_bound)/2
        midpoint_in_arr = Arr[midpoint]

        if search_value == midpoint_in_arr:
            return midpoint
        elif search_value < midpoint_in_arr:
            upper_bound = midpoint - 1;
        elif search_value > midpoint_in_arr:
            lower_bound = midpoint + 1;

    return -1

ans = BinarySearch(x,14)

print(ans)
```

Comment: unless you're interested in writing your own [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), you can use [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you find the midpoint with

```py
midpoint = (lower_bound + upper_bound)/2
```

you get a floating point. You can't use a floating point as an array index, so to solve this you just need to do integer division like so:

```py
midpoint = (lower_bound + upper_bound)//2
```

The second slash `//` tells Python to only divide with integers.

Answer (score -1):

you should cast midpoint to integer:

```
midpoint = int((lower_bound + upper_bound)/2)
```